# Looping through "steps", then "sub-steps", then "sub-sub-steps" in PHP/CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I guess my first question is, since I'm the lone developer, I miss having others to throw ideas off of, or to get ideas when I'm stuck on a problem.  Is there a site that's specific to solving that problem? Like a virtual co-programmer site? Or can StackOverflow work like that?

My main question: I'm working on something like a "to do" list, but each item can possibly have sub-steps... or even sub-sub-steps... and maybe even further. I've got a table with the fields "id, item, parent_id", with all the top-level items having a parent_id = 0. Using Datamapper ORM in CodeIgniter, I'm using this:

```
$i = new Item();
$i->where('parent_id',0)->get();
foreach($i as $item) {
   echo $item->item;
   $si = new Item();
   $si->where('parent_id',$item->id)->get();
   foreach($si as $subItem) {
      echo $subItem->item;
      // and so on
   }
}
```

It works, but is there a smarter way to accomplish this? Some kind of recursive function maybe?

I'm also working on a way to have everything administered by someone else, so they can just drag-and-drop the Items where they need to go... but that's a whole other issue for another day.

Answer (score 3):

If you write your own SQL, you *could* do this in 3 queries.

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE parent_id = 0;"
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM items WHERE parent_id = 0;"
```

However, you look like you want a multi-nested [tree-like structure](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/defining-models%3arelationships%3aforeign-key-associations%3atree-structure):

```
| item |
  | sub-item |
    | sub-sub-item |
```

If you are using CI, there's a (in my opinion) better ORM called [Doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org) that will handle self-referencing tree-like data structures (using recursion as you suggested). Thankfully there is a nice article for incorporating it into CodeIgniter!

http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup

Doctrine will build the query for you - it also supports relationships and a lot of other handy functions like caching that CodeIgniter lacks :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm too far into the project to switch to Doctrine, but reading the documentation, I realized that Datamapper could do something similar.

Comment: You'll find that CI's datamapper is subpar and slow for extensive projects

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would look at implementing a a tree structure. You essentially have the base set up for an adjacency list going here (from the DB point of view - the php code you will still have to write and test). If you add a `level` column to define what level any given tasks is at in its hierarchy you can pull all the data with 1-2 queries by self joining though this will be slow if the nesting level is pretty deep.

An alternative would be using a Nested Set and Preorder Tree Traversal which is a lot more work especially given that it seems you don't need multiple branches for each node.

Have a look at [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) which explains both in detail from the DB side... It's MySQL specific but you should be able to apply the same principles in a DB agnostic way or for another specific DB.

Of course either way you need to implement the mapping for this on the PHP side which is more work than you are doing now... but it also allows you to hit the DB a fewer number of times.

I would also recommend using Doctrine (as Seth also recommended) instead of the CI Datamapper... It has all this implemented already... you just need to learn the basics of Doctrine and get it hooked in to CI which I'm sure there are tons of tutorials on.

Comment: It's all mySQL, and that doc you linked was great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Smth like this , not tested: count($ss)  might not return a good value to see if there are any results returned from the query so please update as necesary ( in Zend i can do count on a Zend_Db_Table_Rowset but not shure what object CI returns and if you can count the number of results ) please update the if statment to call the function only if there are results returned from you're query )

```
    function recursive( $i )
    {
        foreach ( $i as $item )
        {
            echo $item->item;
            $si = new Item();
            $ss = $si->where('parent_id', $item->id)->get();
            if ( count($ss) > 0 ) 
                recursive($ss);
        }
    }
    $i = new Item();
    recursive($i->where('parent_id', 0)->get());
```